# Why doesn't getchar() wait for input?

Tags: c, getchar

I'm writing a Brainfuck interpreter in C. When my program encounters a `,` in the Brainfuck program, it runs `getchar()` and saves the return value in the current memory cell. However, when `getchar()` is run, it immediately returns EOF.

I think this might have something to do with another function which is called at the beginning of the function. `readprog` will read chars from stdin to a dynamically allocated buffer.

Relevant parts of my code:

```c
char *readprog(FILE *stream) {
    char *str = NULL;
    char *tmp = NULL;
    char c;
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t nchars = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) {
        if (size <= nchars) { 
            size += CHUNKSIZE;
            tmp = realloc(str, size);

            if (!tmp) {
                free(str);
                return NULL;
            }

            str = tmp;
        }

        str[nchars] = c;
        ++nchars;
    }

    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char *prog, *array, *ptr;
   int i;

   if (!(prog = readprog(stdin))) {
       free(prog);
       printf("Error reading program: out of memory!");
       return 1;
   }

   array = emalloc(sizeof(*array) * ARRAYSIZE);
   ptr = array;

   for (i = 0; prog[i]; ++i) {
      switch (prog[i]) {

         /* other bf commands */

         case ',':
            printf("gimme input: ");
            *ptr = getchar();
            printf("nice input, it was %d / '%c'\n", *ptr, *ptr);
            break;
         
         /* more bf commands */
      }
   }
}
```

When I run this code and simply input `,`, `getchar()` appears to immediately return -1, or EOF.

```sh
$ printf ',' | ./bf
gimme input: nice input, it was -1 / ''
```

I've tried flushing stdin before calling `getchar()` (yes, I know it has undefined behavior, I only tried it to see if it could lead me to a cleaner solution), calling `getchar()` in a loop until it returned something other than EOF (it returned EOF forever regardless of my input) and switching `getchar()` out for `getc(stdin)` or `fgetc(stdin)`. None of these attempts did anything.

My one hypothesis is that when `readprog` encounters EOF, stdin stops functioning because it assumes that input stream is done. Is there something wrong with my implementation, or is the problem something else?

Comment: Because it is reading a previous newline? `getchar()` reads *everything* from the inpout stream.

Comment: The return value of `getchar()` is `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @WeatherVane But he's getting `-1`, which is EOF, not `\n`

Comment: The `for` loop stops when it gets to a null character, but `readprog` doesn't add a null terminator.

Comment: @Barmar I was looking at the question title. Aside: the same applies to `fgetc()` returning `int` too.

Comment: What are you expecting to read when `,` is the last character in standard input?

Comment: You can use `clearerr(stdin)` to clear the EOF condition. But there still won't be anything to read from the pipe, so you'll continue to get EOF. This is only useful when reading from a terminal (to get past the Ctl-d) or from a file that has been appended to since the last read.

Comment: "readprog encounters EOF, stdin stops functioning because it assumes that input stream is done."  Yes, and it is *right*.  End of file means *end*.  How could we read past the end?

Comment: Maybe you're confused about how input redirection works?  If you have piped input into your program, then stdin *is* the pipe.  Reading stdin will never read the terminal in that case.  If you're thinking that after the pipe data is exhausted then it will start reading the terminal instead, you are mistaken.

Comment: @NateEldredge The same thing happens when I run the program normally, type a `,`, and press Ctrl-D. However, your explanation about reading past the end makes sense, so I assume I will have to modify my program to read a Brainfuck program from a file.

Comment: @Barmar 1. The return value of `getchar()` is implicitly casted to `char` though, right?
2. Thank you for spotting that `readprog` doesn't null-terminate the string.
3. In Brainfuck, `,` is the command to read a character from stdin and save the ascii value to the current memory cell. I added the extra `printf`s are for debugging. You can find a good explanation of the language on Wikipedia.
4. `clearerr(stdin)` does exactly what I need. I'll probably still modify the program to read Brainfuck code from a file instead of stdin, but thank you

Comment: If `char` is unsigned, you won't be able to compare it with `EOF` correctly, since that's usually `-1`.

Comment: @Barmar should I declare `c` as `signed char` then? (I feel like declaring `c` as an `int` obscures its purpose to hold the current character, and would use 3 extra bytes of memory)

Comment: Normally we declare `c` as `int` when it's used as the result of `getchar()`. Don't worry about the 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`printf ',' | ./bf` has `stdin` read from `,`. `./bf` does not read from the terminal after consuming `,`. Therefore, given that `readprog` consumes all of stdin, you will get `EOF` when you call `getchar` after calling `readprog`.